# Pls suggest a classifer for this two class problem with memory constraint

Tags: c, data-mining, classification

Basically I have a device which must be toggled on or off depending on the time. There is a function which checks every 10 minutes and depending on previous data of whether the light was on or off the light must be toggled (two class problem). The issue is that this runs on a microcontroller with 128 kb of memory. So memory is a constraint. Can you guys suggest a model which would classify the above?

Answer (score 1):

It should only take one bit of storage, and on a typical microcontroller one instruction to toggle the value (bitwise `not`, or `xor` with 1, depending on what's available).

Comment: umm.. sorry din quite get that.. my question was if you could suggest a model which uses less space..